# Exception using NotificationManager

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am having an app where an alarm needs to play on a time value stored in the database.When i remove the statement "notification.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;",a notification appears on that alarm time without playing an alarm.when i insert the above statement alarm plays following by force clossing my application.My alarm class is following:

```
public class AlarmManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

sampleDatabase appdb;
SQLiteDatabase sqldb;
Cursor cursor;
int today,prev;
Intent in;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    NotificationManager manger = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon , "Yahrzeit" , System.currentTimeMillis());
    in = new Intent(context,FirstAppActivity.class);
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, in, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "ALERT!!!!", "Time Over" , contentIntent);
    notification.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    appdb = new sampleDatabase(context);
    sqldb = appdb.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = sqldb.query(sampleDatabase.TABLE_SEC, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    today = (int)(cal.getTimeInMillis()/1000);
    Log.e("Naga","Alarm");
    Log.e("today",Integer.toString(today));
    prev = 0;
    cursor.moveToPrevious();
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        int dbdate = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(sampleDatabase.ALARMSET));
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(sampleDatabase.ROW_ID));
        Log.e("dbdate",Integer.toString(dbdate));
        if((dbdate<=today)&&(dbdate>prev))
        {
            manger.cancelAll();
            manger.notify(1, notification);
            sqldb.execSQL("DELETE from " + sampleDatabase.TABLE + " where " + sampleDatabase.ROW_ID + "=" + id);
            sqldb.execSQL("DELETE from "+sampleDatabase.TABLE_SEC + " where " + sampleDatabase.ROW_ID + "=" + id);

        }
        prev = dbdate;
    }
    cursor.close();
    sqldb.close();

}
```

My logcat view is like this(I have inserted permission for vibrate,then also this error comes.):

```
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  start receiver com.nagainfo.firstAp.AlarmManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2821)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:274)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:110)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:90)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at com.nagainfo.firstAp.AlarmManager.onReceive(AlarmManager.java:52)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
 11-14 18:09:18.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(757):     ... 10 more
```

Pls help me.
my manifest is:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".FirstAppActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
            <activity android:name=".addtable"
                      android:label="@string/app_name">
              </activity>
              <activity android:name=".showTime"
                        android:label="@string/app_name">
              </activity>
              <activity android:name=".edittable"
                        android:label="@string/app_name">
              </activity>
               <receiver android:name="AlarmManager">
                </receiver>
              <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
              <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
              <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
</application>
```

Comment: I changed your title.  32 bit and 64 bit OS didn't really work :)

Comment: @ Simon thanks.I have forgotten to change my title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
```

Add the VIBRATE permission to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

You have placed this tag within your application tag.  It should outside the application tag. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="name.xml"
    android:versionCode="24"
    android:versionName="3.4" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".FirstAppActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <activity android:name=".addtable"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".showTime"
               android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".edittable"
               android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="AlarmManager">
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

Comment: I have provided that permission

Comment: Do you mean that you had already provided that permission and it still crashes or that you have added it, and it still crashes?

Comment: @ Simon I have added that thing.then also it crashes.